# How can I make assertions and avoid multiple executions when I test batachable Apex code?

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch

I know that you can test batchable Apex code by calling the Database.executeBatch() function. For example:

`Database.executeBatch( batchable_instance );`

However, I have inconsistent results with any test assertions that I make. Also, the Salesforce documentation says that "you can test only one execution of the *execute* method." How can I avoid executing the *execute* method multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

Database.executeBatch() is an asynchronous call, so you can't be sure when it will execute. To avoid the problem with assertions, surround your code with the Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() functions. For example:

```
Test.startTest();
Database.executeBatch( batchable_instance );
Test.stopTest();
```

The Test.stopStatus() call will force the code to execute if it already hasn’t. Then you should be able to make your assertions.

To avoid executing the *execute* method multiple times, you can use Test.isRunningTest() to add a limit to your query. For example:

`(Test.isRunningTest() ? ' limit 5' : '');`

Comment: Do you see in the debug logs that when wrapped as shown above, execute() gets called more than once? (regardless of using Limit)

Comment: @crop1645 I've only seen that when you set a non-standard batch size, like `Database.executeBatch(batchable_instance, 1)`. In this a limit of 5 should be fine from my experience.

Comment: @ca_peterson - hmm, learned something new. I had always thought that `execute()` in test context was called only once and designed tests accordingly